# Time Machine files cannot be erased

Tags: macos, time-machine

I put Mavericks on my iMac and Time Machine quit updating.  I just want to erase all the TM files on the external HD, but cannot.  Looks like reformating is the only answer. Any solutions? Using SuperDuper! now.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting Time Machine backups can take a very long time, since they can contain hundreds of thousands of files. Moving the files to the trash can take a long time, emptying the trash can take a long time, and using command line "rm" commands can take a long time. By long time I mean tens of hours.

Usually the fasted way to remove such numbers of files is to use Disk Utility to erase and/or reformat and/or repartition the drive. Copy anything you don't want lost off of the drive, reformat it, and start the TM process again.

Comment: It is not a matter of waiting, it tells me I cannot erase the files.  Reformatting the HD is the only solution I know.  Thanks Apple for not giving the administrator of the machine the power to do what he wants! Microsoft is looking better all the time.  Apple = STUPID!